# Failing to add custom Buttons to Android Title Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a main `Activity` and I want to add a couple of buttons to the `ActionBar`. As I understand it, it's the bar with the title of the app and the 3 dots that function as a menu. This is the code I've implementend:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .....
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setCustomView(new TitleButtonView(this));
 }
```

And TitleButtonView is simply:

```
public class TitleButtonView extends LinearLayout {

    public TitleButtonView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,50));
        Button b = new Button(context);
        Button b1 = new Button(context);
        b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,50));
        b1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,50));
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        addView(b);
        addView(b1);
        b.setText("Boton");
        b1.setText("Otro");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it not working because the setCustoView is used for something else?

Comment: What is happening? Can we have an error message or a stack trace perhaps?

Comment: You need to call [ActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(boolean))

Comment: Ohh Sorry. It was not showing. But @adneal was right. The show custom was not being called. I added the line that made it worked. Thanks for  the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well after reading a little bit more, I found that this is the line that needs to be added.

ab.setDisplayOptions(ab.getDisplayOptions()|ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

It tells the action bar to show custom views.

Sorry for any trouble